# SQLAlchemy send a query with an accent character to MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, encoding, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I'm working with
 - **Python 2.7.11**
 - **SQLAlchemy 1.1.3.**
 - **pymssql 2.1.3**

On Windows 10

I've some troubles with a particular query string that contains the special character 'à'. The string is encoded with Latin-1 so I perfoms the decode in this way

```
>>> query = "exec CFG.cfg.mystore_proc 'PARAM1', 'PARAM2', 'dbo_società'"
>>> query = query.decode("latin1")
>>> query
u"exec CFG.cfg.mystore_proc  'PARAM1', 'PARAM2', 'dbo_societ\x85'"
>>> query = query.encode("utf8")
>>> query
"exec CFG.cfg.mystore_proc  'PARAM1', 'PARAM2', 'dbo_societ\xc2\x85'"
>>> db.session.execute(query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bulonea\projects\mercurial\DWHUI\WebSite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1101, in execute
clause = expression._literal_as_text(clause)
  File "C:\Users\bulonea\projects\mercurial\DWHUI\WebSite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 4232, in _literal_as_text
return TextClause(util.text_type(element))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've created the engine in this way

```
SQLA.create_engine(connection_string, poolclass=poolclass, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: `util.text_type(element)` is probably effectively `unicode(element)` in python 2, so it is implicitly trying to decode your binary string as ascii (the default in python 2). Try passing the original decoded unicode and let SQLA handle encoding.

Comment: Yes it works,
I thought to have already done this try but probably there was some other issue when I did.
Thank you!